# pls notice that r is a rational number:) how to solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^r -1}{x-1}$ without using L Hospital?

Tags: analysis, limits

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^r -1}{x-1}$

r is Rational_number,
with L Hospital rule is this easy to solve, but how could I solve it in another way?

Comment: Notice that this is exactly the derivative of $x^r$ evaluated in $x = 1$.

Comment: The mean value theorem for $f(x) = x^r$ gives you the existence of a $\xi$ in $(x,1)$ s.t.
$$\frac{x^r-1}{x-1} = f'(\xi) = r\xi^{r-1}$$
For $x\to 1$ also $\xi \to 1$ hence
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^r-1}{x-1} = \lim_{\xi\to 1} r\xi^{r-1} = r$$

Answer (score 3):

We know that $$x^r-1 = (x-1)(x^{r-1} + x^{r-2} +\cdots +1)$$ Thus, $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^r-1}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} (x^{r-1} + x^{r-2} +\cdots +1) = r$$

Comment: what if if r <0? does it hold?

Comment: Even more interesting, perhaps: what if $\;r\;$ is not even an integer?

Comment: Suppose that this limit exists. I can suppose that $r = \frac{a}{b} $ and $a, b \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Then I have $$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{\frac{a}{b}} -1}{x-1} = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{\frac{a}{b}} -1}{x-1}  = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{(x^{\frac{1}{b}})^a -1}{(x^{\frac{1}{b}})^b-1}. $$ Put $t = x^{\frac{1}{b}}$ and I will do as Rohan.